# How to add total deaths under player username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was watching a CallMeCarson video where he was playing on his Minecraft server, and I noticed that the server had a death counter, but under the players username. I am wondering how I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scoreboard display slot, just like the sidebar and the player list.

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay <scoreboardName> belowName
```